# Shaded tittle does not displayed properly

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color, shadow

I list my projects [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/projects/). All share the same style for the tittle, with a dark background for the inner body of the border the tittle lives in. However, my latest project got a logo ( :) ) which does not allow for a dark background. The reason as you can see [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/projects/#geraf) is that the mouth of the giraffe is brown, thus a dark background does not match nicely.

The code for the header is this:

```
<h1 style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;font-size:27px;letter-spacing:2px;
  text-shadow:2px 2px #330000 , 3px 3px #330033 , 4px 4px #330066 , 5px 5px #330099;
  color:black;text-align:center;letter-spacing:2px;border:2px solid;
  border-radius:25px;border-color:#CCCC99;box-shadow:10px 5px 5px #CC9966;
  border-style:outset;-moz-background-size:20% 100%;background-size:20% 100%;
  background-image:url('myurl');-moz-border-radius:25px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;width:70%;position:relative;top:50%;left:15%;"><span style="padding-left:20px;font-size:30px;line-height:6em;"><b>kd-GeRaF</b></span>
</h1>
```

Unfortunately, I can not use a CSS folder, thus I am putting it in the HTML code.

The problem is that the shaded tittle will not be displayed nicely with a white background, as you can see in the link above. I tried several combinations of colors in order to make it display nicely, but I failed. How should I do it?

Comment: Are you asking which colour shadow will go nice with your image?

Comment: No, because that would be off topic @GeorgeLee. I am asking which colour shadow would allo the title to be shown. Now, nobody can read it! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question for stackoverflow, anyway, why don't you go with the giraffe color and a smooth shadow?

```
<h1 style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-weight:300;font-size:27px;letter-spacing:2px;text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .4);color: #f8bf63;text-align:center;letter-spacing:2px;border:2px solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#CCCC99;box-shadow:10px 5px 5px #CC9966;border-style:outset;-moz-background-size:20% 100%;background-size:20% 100%;background-image:url('https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/giraffe_sam.png');-moz-border-radius:25px;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:70%;position:relative;top:50%;left:15%;"><span style="padding-left:20px;font-size:30px;line-height:6em;"><b>kd-GeRaF</b></span></h1>
```

Comment: That's it! Well, I did not ask for how to improve, but for how to make it "visible", because it got tangled up with the shadows, thanks! Jonas, I really like it that way, I will upvote your top answer too, as a way of say thank-you! :)